# PHP(32-bit) 2GB Range Download

Tags: php, nginx, 32bit-64bit

I have the following problem: I have a php webpage which:

- is running on a raspberry pi(32bit)
- should deliver files for download which are bigger than 2 GB
- files are access protected, which means, that you only are allow to download the file depending on a condition in the php code
- must support HTTP range requests

I have a solution for deliver files with range requests from php, but in this solution I'm using fseek, which doesn't work for files bigger that 2GB and I can not figure out how to solve that problem.

I'm using nginx and php7-fpm if this is relevant for you.

Comment: I have no idea if https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php#112647 still works, but worth a try perhaps?

Comment: I have not tried it myself, but I read that it will not work. But I will try it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which solves the problem for me. Instead of trying to send the file from the php script, I use an feature of nginx.

Nginx offers a possibility to redirect a request to an existing file, but only from an internal redirect via the "X-Accel-Redirect" header.

Documentation: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile/

It seems to be possible with other severs too, but it definitiv work with nginx.

Comment: This is the best solution anyway.  Takes the load off your application server, lets the web server do what it does best.